# jq parse for multiple values

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to output displayName from JSON which has both

```
"source": "0.0.0.0/0" and
tcpOptions": "destinationPortRange": "min": 80
```

The result should display only

```
rule-1
```

eg: JSON

```
[
  {
    "displayName": "rule-1",
    "secrule": [
      {
        "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "tcpOptions": {
          "destinationPortRange": {
            "min": 80,
            "max": 80
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "tcpOptions": {
          "destinationPortRange": {
            "min": 443,
            "max": 443
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "displayName": "rule-2",
    "secrule": [
      {
        "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "tcpOptions": {
          "destinationPortRange": {
            "min": 443,
            "max": 443
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "20.0.0.0/0",
        "tcpOptions": {
          "destinationPortRange": {
            "min": 80,
            "max": 80
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.secrule[].source == "0.0.0.0/0" and .secrule[].tcpOptions.destinationPortRange.min == 80) | .displayName' JSON | sort -u
```

But it displays both rules (which is incorrect)

```
rule-1
rule-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expanding `.secrule` twice, thus every combination of its elements get checked. Use `any` instead:

```
.[] | select(any(.secrule[]; .source=="0.0.0.0/0" and .tcpOptions.destinationPortRange.min==80)).displayName
```